# Can not locate a file in a bash script?

Tags: windows, bash

I am running a shell script which expects a file in a directory but I can not seem to locate it.

This is my shell script

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

    # expects a file to be present in current directory called INPUT_FILE
    # this is the value set in the jenkins config

        if [ ! -f INPUT_FILE ] ;then
            echo "file ${INPUT_FILE} does not exist"
            exit 1
        fi
```

And in windows I am running a shell script from a directory like this

```
D:\scripts> ./all/script.sh
```

I tried to put `INPUT_FILE.csv` in `scripts` folder and also in `all` folder but it does not seem to work. Where should this file be present?

Comment: There seem to be a typo in this script `[ ! -f INPUT_FILE ]` is testing for a file literal name `INPUT_FILE`. It was probably meant to be `[ ! -f "$INPUT_FILE" ]` instead. Hopefully, the environment variable `INPUT_FILE` is provided by the Jenkins continuous integration somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct filename.
Windows hides the extension of a file, when you look for INPUT_FILE.csv use

```
if [ ! -f INPUT_FILE.csv ] ;then
   echo "file INPUT_FILE.csv does not exist"
   exit 1
fi
```

You tried to use the variable INPUT_FILE. When you want this, try

```
input_file="INPUT_FILE.csv"
if [ ! -f "${input_file}" ]; then
   echo "file ${input_file} does not exist"
   exit 1
fi
```

Also note that `bash` is case sensitive, so `INPUT_FILE.csv` is different from `input_file.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to list files first to verify the extension and all file names in the directory then check for the existence of the files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ALL_FILES=$(ls -I "*.sh") # This will list all file except .sh
echo "Files in current Directory $ALL_FILES"
INPUT_FILE="INPUT_FILE" # or     INPUT_FILE="INPUT_FILE.csv" 
     if [ ! -f $INPUT_FILE ] ;then
            echo "file ${INPUT_FILE} does not exist"
            exit 1
    else
          echo "file  exist ${INPUT_FILE}"
          exit 0

fi
```

The first advantage, It will list all the file and the second one, If exist you will get the output.
[image]